# MATLAB: Write strings and numbers of variables in files

Tags: file, matlab, cell

I have following data:

```
a=[3 1 6]';
b=[2 5 2]';
c={'ab' 'bc' 'cd'}';
```

I now want to make a file which looks like this (the delimiter is tab):

```
ab    3    2
bc    1    5 
cd    6    2
```

my solution (with a loop) is:

```
a=[3 1 6]';
b=[2 5 2]';
c={'ab' 'bc' 'cd'}';
c=cell2mat(c);
fid=fopen('filename','w');
for i=1:numel(b)

    fprintf(fid,'%s\t%u\t%u\n',c(i,:),a(i),b(i));

end

fclose(fid);
```

Is there a possibility without loop and/or the possibility to write cell arrays directly in files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
%A cell array holding all data
%    (Note transpose)
data = cat(2, c, num2cell(a), num2cell(b))';
```

Write data to a file

```
fid = fopen('example.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s\t%u\t%u\n', data{:});
fclose(fid);
```

This will be memory wasteful if your datasets get large (probably better to leave then as separate variables and loop), but seems to work.

Comment: Incidentally, it seems like `dlmwrite` or some variant should be able to do this as well, but I can't seem to find the write call to use.